# Verificação de login e senha

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Preciso de ajuda para uma verificação de um login e senha.

Se o login e senha que eu digitar no `JTextField` forem iguais a que tenho no banco, não pode permitir o cadastro, o que estou procurando não é uma validação e sim apenas uma verificação de rotina no cadastro de um funcionário.

Fiz este método porém não consigo fazer a verificação do login e senha já existentes, para que não seja possível o cadastro, caso já exista no banco!

```
private boolean verificaLoginSenha( JTextField txtLogin, JTextField txtSenha){        
        String login = null;
        String senha = null;         
        if((!txtLogin.getText().equals(login)  && (!txtSenha.getText().equals(senha) )) ){
            return true;            
        }
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi @Diego F. Poderia ajudar com algum exemplo??

Comment: comece  recebendo o login do usuario e senha...  ai pra vc verificar se esse login ja existe no seu banco .. faca um for rodando todo o seu banco apenas com o login do usuario  para ver se existe  e depois vc retorna true ou false...

Comment: Muito obrigada @Diego F se eu entendesse muito bem não estaria aqui no fórum fazendo perguntas estaria como vc dando "respostas" !!!

Comment: @Tiago obg!! Vou tentar!!

Comment: @Lizy não foi uma critica, foi apenas uma sugestão. Não me entenda mal. Eu estava prestes a responder essa pergunta, por isso sugeri o link. Mas se você não compreendesse o conteudo do outro, eu teria que fazer uma resposta grande explicando coisas fora da pergunta. Enfim, boa sorte :)